# Japanese Transliteration in Node.js and Kakasi

Tags: node.js, transliteration, cjk

I have written a little wrapper for [Kakasi](https://github.com/loretoparisi/kakasi)

that is like the following:

```
Kakasi.prototype.transliterate = function (data) {
            var self = this;
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                var args;
                args = [
                    '-i',
                    'euc',
                    '-Ha',
                    '-Ka',
                    '-Ja',
                    '-Ea',
                    '-ka',
                    '-s',
                    '-iutf8',
                    '-outf8'
                ];
                var kakasi = spawn(self._options.bin, args, {});
                console.log( "echo \""+data+"\" | " + kakasi.spawnargs.join(' ') )
                args = [
                    data
                ];
                var echo = spawn('echo', args, {});

                echo.stdout.pipe( kakasi.stdin );
                var res='';
                kakasi.stdout.on('data', function(_data) {
                    var data=new Buffer(_data,'utf-8').toString();
                    res+=data;
                });
                kakasi.stdout.on('end', function(_) {
                    return resolve(res);
                });
                kakasi.on('error', function(error) {
                    return reject(error);
                });

                if (self._options.debug) kakasi.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

            });
        }//transliterate
```

This code basically does the following command

```
echo "退屈であくびばっかしていた毎日" | kakasi -i euc -Ha -Ka -Ja -Ea -ka -s -iutf8 -outf8
```

that outputs `taikutsu deakubibakkashiteita mainichi`
Problem is that the javascript is missing some output infact:

```
$ node transliterate.js 
echo "退屈であくびばっかしていた毎日" | kakasi -i euc -Ha -Ka -Ja -Ea -ka -s -iutf8 -outf8
----------
deakubibakkashiteita
```

---

The input parameters are the same, but for some reason (encoding?) the child output to `stdout` is different.

The **kakasi.js** code is available [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/kakasi.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your dictionary loader causes this problem. You should flip the dictionaries as follows.

```
process.env.KANWADICTPATH = resolve('./data/kanwadict');
process.env.ITAIJIDICTPATH = resolve('./data/itaijidict');
```

instead of

```
process.env.KANWADICTPATH = resolve('./data/itaijidict');
process.env.ITAIJIDICTPATH = resolve('./data/kanwadict');
```

Comment: hey @goemon! that was the issue!!! Thanks a lot! I have updated the codebase! https://github.com/loretoparisi/kakasi.js